# Importing Polars in a notebook causes kernel to crash

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-polars

Importing Polars polars==0.19.7 makes my kernel crash
logs :

```
import polars
```

```
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

```
15:51:25.818 [info] Restarted 58cbe489-1e15-4ee8-a740-73c20717dff4
15:51:30.344 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 0 for ~/dev/playground/test.ipynb
15:51:30.352 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 0 @ 1699973490351
15:51:30.447 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: 
15:51:30.448 [info] Dispose Kernel process 6740.
15:51:30.462 [info] End cell 0 execution @ undefined, started @ 1699973490351, elapsed time = -1699973490.351s
```

Would any one know what is causing this ?

Comment: Python, Jupyter, ipython versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12292

Do you want Polars to run on an old CPU (e.g. dating from before 2011),
or on an x86-64 build of Python on Apple Silicon under Rosetta? Install
`pip install polars-lts-cpu`. This version of Polars is compiled without
AVX target features.

"Celeron" and "Pentium" processors won't have AVX (even after 2011)

https://www.ikmultimedia.com/faq/?id=1254

`lscpu` will tell you your processor family on ubuntu

Comment: Yes the issue is on apple silicon ! thank you very much